# Make IIS site files uploaded only viewable by auth. users

Tags: authentication, iis

We have a website which will be public facing, www.mywebsite.com,  it will go to a login screen for all employees to login where all credentials and users are authenicated by what is in MS SQL.

when they upload a file it will be saved into a folder with a filepath,  www.mywebsite.com/folder/myfile.pdf

Currently, anybody can take that url and copy/paste it into a browser and view the file.  I do not want it to behave this way.

How can I lock down the files so only authenticated users that are logged into the website can view the files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only way to achieve this with pure IIS is create an FTP site instead. Then IIS user isolation will only people view these files uploaded by himself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/ftpserver/userisolation/

The second way to achieve this with your web application is create a table in your MS SQL to record  all uploaded file name and their upload users. Then only list files based on the user column. You might have to make some change in your application level.

Comment: Yes we do that as well.  All files and filenames are in a table with the userID of who uploaded it, filename, date,  doc type, etc... 
 All users should be able to view all files we just need to avoid the issue of anybody with the filepath can view the file.